# mike42/escpos-php UTF-8 no print Cyrillic

Tags: php, utf-8, printing

I like to print `Cyrillic` on my `XPRINTER XP-58 pos` printer.

I tried below code but it doens't print all the letters and if so it prints the print-out badly. This is what I got as a result of this code, but not all letters are missing:
 ---- Ѕ Ј К Љ Њ Ќ Ѓ --------- LETTERS

If there is anyone with experience in this please help me. Thank you in advance,

My code:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = "";
    $data['test'] = array(['А Б В Г Д Ѓ Е Ж З Ѕ И Ј К Л Љ М Н Њ О П Р С Т Ќ У Ф Х Ц Ч Џ Ш']);
    $this->load->library("EscPos.php");
    try {        
        $connector = new Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector("XP-58");
        $profile = Escpos\CapabilityProfiles\DefaultCapabilityProfile::getInstance();
        $printer = new Escpos\Printer($connector,$profile);
        foreach ($data['test'] as $artikli){
            $printer -> text(iconv("UTF-8","GBK//IGNORE", "$artikli[0]") . "\n");
        }
        $printer -> text("\n\n\n");
        $printer -> cut();

        /* Close printer */
        $printer -> close();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Couldn't print to this printer: " . $e -> getMessage() . "\n";
    }
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
```

[image: Picture of what is being printed right now]

Comment: For one, GBK is an encoding for Chinese characters so that's not going to help with printing Cyrillic at all.

Comment: What to put, for Macedonian

Comment: Beats me, I'd suggest picking a supported encoding from your printer's specs. `cp1251` is probably a good bet. You're probably also going to want to *explicitly* configure the connection to set the charset because it doesn't matter if you're feeding a properly-encoded string to the printer if the printer hasn't been told what that encoding is.

Answer (score 0):

Your printer seems to use Kanji mode by default.

1. Cancel Kanji mode
   https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=177
2. Select correct codepage and encoding pair (for me it were enc 866, codepage 17 for Russian, enc 852 and cp 18 for Czech, but you seem too look for Macedonian)
3. Send your data.