# I'm using go language to print to a POS printer, but got bad prints of Chinese charater. (English is OK)

Tags: go, pos

I'm using [this](https://github.com/alexbrainman/printer) go package, and everything is good. But got bad prints of Chinese characters. I'm not good at this kind of low-level / hardware / encoding things. So someone give a hint how can I correct my code.

Updated code：

```
func main() {
    testWindowPrinter()
}

func testWindowPrinter() {
    // all have bad prints
    printLines(simplifiedchinese.GBK.NewDecoder().Reader(strings.NewReader("你好")))
    printLines(simplifiedchinese.HZGB2312.NewDecoder().Reader(strings.NewReader("你好")))
    printLines(strings.NewReader("你好"))
}

func printLines(lines ...io.Reader) error {
    var defaultPrinter, err = printer.Default()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(1, err.Error())
        return err
    }

    p, err := printer.Open(defaultPrinter)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(2, err.Error())
        return err
    }
    defer p.Close()

    err = p.StartRawDocument("test")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(3, err.Error())
        return err
    }
    defer p.EndDocument()

    err = p.StartPage()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(4, err.Error())
        return err
    }

    // Am I doing right here?
    for i := range lines {
        var bf = new(bytes.Buffer)
        n, err := bf.ReadFrom(lines[i])
        if err != nil {
            println(err.Error())
        } else {
            println(n)
            fmt.Fprintln(p, bf.String())
        }
    }

    err = p.EndPage()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(5, err.Error())
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

More details
zsbd

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your environment.

If you are executing this Go program in a Windows CMD ([which only supports UTF16 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10765469/6309)), you will see strange characters.
See "[How to properly output a string in a Windows console with go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12053168/6309)" as an example.
You need to convert those characters before printing them out.

Comment: Thanks @VonC, yeah I executed the code in Windows CMD, I'll check the link. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @VonC, I still get bad prints using `charmap.ISO8859_1`. I lookup my CMD settings and it says code page CP936, but I can't find it in `golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap`. So any suggestions?

Comment: @Leeds It now is in https://github.com/golang/text/blob/master/encoding/charmap/charmap.go

Comment: oops Chinese related is located in `text/encoding/simplifiedchinese`. But I still get the bad prints. this issue makes me crazy!

Comment: @Leeds Did yu change the font of your CMD console? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22828826/6309): Lucida or Consola.

Comment: Hi @VonC, nope and my CMD settings does not has Font like Lucida and Consola. I'm guessing the package (https://github.com/alexbrainman/printer) does not support Chinese?

Comment: @Leeds It does, but your console must use a compatible font: https://www.isunshare.com/windows-8/change-font-font-size-and-layout-in-cmd.html and https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-more-fonts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/

Comment: Just making sure I describe my issue right, I'm printing to POS-printer, not CMD console. Is my issue related to CMD conosle?

Comment: @Leeds I missed the "POS printer" part (I am not familiar with this): CMD is just a way to validate your output.

Comment: Hi @VonC, I updated my code, would like double review my code?

Comment: Looks good, but the issue might be on the printer side. For instance: https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/issues/254

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48421498/6309. Both links are not for Go but can give an idea of what is needed. Nice illustration: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48531109/6309

Comment: I'm sure the POS-printer is OK, because it works fine if I use a commercial cashier software. Only got bad prints when I run my code. I'll check the links you suggested and ping you back here later. Thanks @VonC